# jQuery getting data out of div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm doing something wrong but cannot figure out what. I have a set of filters that have `data` attribute in them. When I click on them, I retrieve that value, and I need to store it to a div element in it's `data` attribute.

```
<ul class="filters">
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-term="bla">Click</a>
        <a href="#" data-term="Bla">Click</a>
        <a href="#" data-term="BLA">Click</a>
        <a href="#" data-term="Blah">Click</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="data_div" data-term="">Data value is <span></span></div>
```

jQuery is

```
jQuery('.filters li a').on('click', function(){
    var term = jQuery(this).data('term');
     $('#data_div').data('term', term);
});

var term = jQuery('#data_div').data('term');

jQuery('#data_div span').text( "" + term );
```

I'm doing this because I don't know how else to get the value of the local variable `term` inside the function that happens on click. So I want to store that attribute to a div from which I can then access it for later use.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6eygbafb/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/21wqwb07/, You need to set span text in the click handler

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code as it is, you probably just meant to add the `jQuery('#data_div span').text(` in another event-driven callback (otherwise it'll just run once, with an empty string)

Comment: As Satpal demonstrates, you need the updating script part _inside_ the click function.

Comment: I needed `.attr('data-term', term);` Once I set this it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works get the value by attr:

```
$('.filters li a').on('click', function(){
    var term = $(this).attr('data-term');
     $('#data_div').text('data is' + term);
    console.log(term);
});

var term = $('#data_div').attr('data-term');

$('#data_div span').text( "" + term );
```

fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/6eygbafb/5/

Comment: I know you downvoted my answer. Please remove downvote because I didn't stole your fiddle

Answer (score 3):

If I get you right that you want to get value of local variable "term" inside click function and use it somewhere outside. Then, just move it outside click function scope, make it global.

```
var term;

jQuery('.filters li a').on('click', function(){
    term = jQuery(this).data('term');
});
```

Comment: Tried this, didn't work. Got undefined error when I tried to use it.

Comment: Where/how did you use it?

Comment: I defined global variable term, then set variable term in the function, and when I try to see it with console.log, I get nothing (outside of the function). When I put console.log inside the function, it outputs it properly.

Comment: This should work: https://jsfiddle.net/gvkb3hq1/.
First alert statement will not alert anything.
Make sure you have clicked on some link. :D.
And then when you click on "view later content" link, it will alert some value.

Comment: Yeah, it works, I tested this on a new issue I had :)

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
jQuery('.filters li a').on('click', function(){
    var term = jQuery(this).attr('data-term');
     $('#data_div').attr('data-term', term);

    var term = jQuery('#data_div').attr('data-term');

jQuery('#data_div span').text( "" + term );
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6eygbafb/6/)

Comment: And see my fiddle care fully this is fully different from yours @SjoerdDeWit

Answer (score 1):

Update the text and attribute inside the click function

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6eygbafb/2/)

You can use

```
$('#data_div').attr('data-term', term);
```

to get the value outside the click function for later use